# Seeking most natural unit of analysis in between US county and state

Tags: united-states, county

Do you have any suggestions for the most natural unit of analysis in between US county and state?

I am looking at Core Based Statistical Areas but those don't seem to cover all counties.

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to search/ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thank you. I will post there.

Comment: I don't believe the OP is asking where to find a data source but rather asking what geospatial units exist in US data between the county and state level. To some extent the answer will depend on what sort of analysis is desired. But more generally, I don't believe such a "natural unit" exists, at least not uniformly across the US as states have widely varying standards for what a county is. NM, for example, has 33 counties. With the exception of Los Alamos county, the rest range from 1000 to 9000 sq miles in area. The largest county in NJ, on the other hand, is 800 sq miles.

Comment: Thank you. That is indeed the sort of answer I was looking for. I would suggest posting it as the answer. I agree what is "natural" depends on the analysis. What I was thinking of was something similar to states and counties, which are "natural" in the sense that they are the most prominent administrative boundaries in the US for their level of geographic granularity.